# Contain table within div

Tags: html, css, html-table

Given this example, try making your window smaller such that the size of the example is squished.

```css
div {
    padding: 1em;
    background: #2424c6
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}

input {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

You will note that the textboxes (correctly) do not wrap to new lines as they are in individual `<td>`s.

However, the containing `div`, as denoted by the blue colour, does not completely wrap the table.

How can I make the containing `div` fully contain the child `table`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table overflowing outside of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259189/table-overflowing-outside-of-div)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add [`display:table`](http://www.brunildo.org/test/disptable.html) to the wrapping div.

```css
div {
    padding: 1em;
    background: #2424c6;
    display: table;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}

input {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, but this only works if you fix the widths of the table elements in advance :).

Comment: It’s always struck me as hacky to add `display: table` to things that aren’t tables, but +1 because this works.

Comment: I agree, but without knowing the width of the content or dynamically changing width with JS ...

Comment: It’s also worth noting that this works when the `div` contains any arbitrary oversized content (for example `img`), not just a `table`.

Comment: ooo good to know. If it wasn't for this question forcing me to to do 5 seconds of research I still wouldn't know about `display:table`. Thanks SO!

Comment: Thanks, I tried this initially but it doesn't work in IE7 (which is my lowest common denominator browser) but I didn't specify it should so you get the accept.

Comment: IE7! Lucky b*stard! Mine is IE6 :( Thanks. To get it working in IE7 you could try some JS that detects the total width of the table and sets the relevant width to the wrapping div, not ideal but...

Comment: I think `display:inline-block` should work as well; it also doesn't feel as 'hacky' as `display:table`